# statement causing form to submit without validation

Tags: javascript

I have been tearing my hair trying to figure out why adding a line of text to an `if` statement would cause a form to submit without validating.

Here is the part of the code which is causing the issue:

```
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
// if first name is empty
if (firstName.value == "") {
    var fnError = document.getElementById("fnError");
    fnError.innerHTML = "*Please enter your first name";
    fnResult = false;
} else { 
    // Store firstName using local storage
    localStorage.setItem("firstName", firstName.value);
}
```

I am trying to enter the following line of code into the `else` statement:

```
fnError.innerHTML = "";
```

The form is validated using an `onsubmit` event handler:

```
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("formUser");
btnSubmit.onsubmit = validate;
```

And the validate function returns either `true` or `false` depending on whether the validation's conditions are met. All of this currently works well until I try to add that line of code and then the form is sent the next time the user presses the submit button regardless of whether the conditions are met or not.

I am new to JavaScript, so it is possible that I am missing something obvious.

Many thanks!

Comment: There's important code missing. Can you complete it, or otherwise, create a jsfiddle where you can show the problem? I'd write `required` inside every required form field as in `<input required ...>`.

Comment: Is "formUser" the id of your form? Are you getting any exceptions in your browser's console?

Comment: Please show how you declare `fnResult` variable. May be it gets bound to `window` context?

Comment: I can't post all of the code as it is for assessment and there would then be issues with plagiarism - it's very frustrating. I am trying to edit that second statement to say: fnError.innerHTML = "";. Clearing the error message. formUser is the ID of the form and fnResult is declared at the top of the function like this: var fnResult = true;

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia It's still nice to have a JavaScript fallback for those whose browsers do not support the `required` attribute.

Comment: also, it's a requirement of the assignment that validation is done using JavaScript

Comment: @Spooky I never said not to have javascript validation, I only mean to **also** put the `required`, in case some modern browser has javascript turned off or there's any problem with javascript that prevents it from running.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia It seemed as though you were offering it as a solution to his JavaScript problem (since that is what this discussion is about).

Comment: @Spooky sorry, it was only an extra recommendation though my wording could have been better (I'm not English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible problem: If you're inserting the offending line into your code as shown below, your function is failing before it returns a value. In the "else" block, fnError would be in scope, but its value would be undefined. Attempting to set a property on an undefined value causes an error.

```
} else { 
    // Store firstName using local storage
    fnError.innerHTML = "";
    localStorage.setItem("firstName", firstName.value);
}
```

To fix this, move the following line before the "if" block:

```
var fnError = document.getElementById("fnError");
```

Now the fnError variable will contain a valid reference to the error-message element in both the "if" and the "else" block.